# JPA - Existe a possibilidade de usar MatchMode.ANYWHERE com Predicate

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

Normalmente quando preciso fazer uma busca pegando um resultado através de uma única palavra, usando *Criteria* e *Restrictions* faço da seguinte forma:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("nome", filtro.getNome(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

No caso acima usando *MatchMode.ANYWHERE* para um produto que tem no seu nome a palavra Caderno, eu posso digitar somente Caderno que é gerado uma lista com todos os nomes que possui Caderno no nome.

Devido a uma necessidade do projeto, estou tendo que fazer a pesquisa de uma forma diferente, então resolvi fazer um teste usando *Predicate* Segue a classe de teste completa:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import br.com.lefacil.papelaria.modelo.ProdutoPap;

public class TesteBDCriteria implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static List<ProdutoPap> pesquisarProdutos(){

        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("xxPU");
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();

        EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();
        trx.begin();

        CriteriaBuilder cb = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ProdutoPap>
                 cq = cb.createQuery(ProdutoPap.class);

            Root<ProdutoPap> produtoRoot = cq.from(ProdutoPap.class);

            Long idEmpresaLogado = 1L;
            String sku = null;
            String nomeProduto = "Caderno";
            //Caderno Universitário 1 Matéria  50 Folhas - Tilibra
            Predicate prod = cb.equal(produtoRoot.get("empresa"), idEmpresaLogado);
            Predicate condicoes = null;

            if(idEmpresaLogado != null) {
                condicoes = cb.and(prod);
            }

            if(idEmpresaLogado != null && sku == null && nomeProduto != null) {
                System.out.println("Entrou no sku == null nome não nulo");
                Predicate nomes = produtoRoot.get("nome").in(nomeProduto);
                condicoes = cb.and(prod,nomes);
            }

            TypedQuery<ProdutoPap> tq = manager.createQuery(cq.select(produtoRoot).where(condicoes));

            trx.commit();   
            return tq.getResultList();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ProdutoPap> produtos = pesquisarProdutos();

        for(ProdutoPap p: produtos) {
            System.out.println(p.getNome());
        }
    }
}
```

Existe alguma forma de ao usar:

```
Predicate nomes = produtoRoot.get("nome").in(nomeProduto);
```

eu consiga fazer a pesquisa usando somente um trecho dos dados, como no exemplo com *MatchMode.ANYWHERE*.

Answer (score 0):

Tive a mesma necessidade e pesquisei diversas soluções na internet que não usasse customizações do dialeto SQL do banco de dados usado pelo provedor JPA. A solução menos ruim que consegui foi como no exemplo a seguir:

```
            Expression<String> field = root.get(Entity_.attribute);
            Expression<String> fieldTranslate = criteriaBuilder.function("TRANSLATE", String.class, field, criteriaBuilder.literal(AcentosUtil.getListaComAcentos()), criteriaBuilder.literal(AcentosUtil.getListaSemAcentos()));
            Expression<String> fieldLower = criteriaBuilder.lower(fieldTranslate);              
            String valueTranslate = AcentosUtil.removeAcentos(parameter);
            String valueLower = valueTranslate.toLowerCase();
            Expression<String> valueIlike = criteriaBuilder.literal("%" + valueLower + "%");
            
            predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, criteriaBuilder.like(fieldLower, valueIlike));
```